# How do I obtain the x-value of highlighted point when using Charts UI?

Tags: swift, xcode, coordinates, ios-charts

I have a variable that changes depending on the x-value of the point as defined by the user on the graph. How do I go about this? I need the x-coordinate of the point in order to change another view.

Right now, I have a simple CombinedChart. What I want is when apoint is highlighted, the x-coordinate is then obtained, and this changes a label. (For example, if the person clicks on (1,3), the label will display "1"

I have tried:

```
Global.chiller1x = Double(chiller1Chart.xAxis.labelPosition.rawValue)
print(String(format: "%.2f", Global.chiller1x ?? 0))
```

I have also looked at getMarkerPosition, etc but none seem to have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Chart Delegate (`ChartViewDelegate`) method `chartValueSelected()` to capture user click with X & Y value on that touch points.

Use Below Method:

```
extension LineChartViewController: ChartViewDelegate{
    public func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
        //Print Value like entry.x & entry.y
    }
}
```

Hope this will helps you to get user touch with X & Y values.